# ng-init not initialize data in pagination, angularjs

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angularjs-ng-init

I'm using angularjs and angular pagination to show users detail.
Here, I use `ng-init` to initialize age of users. If there is age in user's detail then it will show otherwise it show default age 10. 
Please see the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kQbgJMXfMV87eU15FLvC?p=preview)

`ng-init` works fine first time but when I move to next page it is not showing default age i.e.10.
For example: in Page 3, name is name30 and there is no age. So, age should come from default age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngInit` directive allows you to evaluate an expression in the current scope. The problem with your approach is that `ngInit` is called only once when scope is created - so it works properly only for page 1.

Also check out what is says in [AngularJs documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/docs/api/ng/directive/ngInit):

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties
>   of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should
>   use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

So based on this recommendation it would be better to set default age value in the controller like:

```
  // assign value on page change.
  $scope.loadRecord = function(page) {
    $scope.user = $scope.users[page-1];

    if (!$scope.user.age) {
      $scope.user.age = 10;
    }
  };

  // initial value
  $scope.loadRecord(1);
```

Please check out this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ovK0glYiXKJfqJ2M1ai3?p=preview) to se it in action.

Comment: plunkr is giving error after page 4 & onwards click

Comment: Actually this is not related to the question but anyway thanks for letting me know. I've just fixed it.

Comment: one more thing, your code & mine code looks same.. :P

Comment: True. I guess it's the most appropriate solution that's why our code looks similar.

Comment: Thanks for you compliment..bdw I've added answer before you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ng-init` logic & also you supposed to move UI logic to your controller

**Markup**

```
<h4>Limit the maximum visible buttons</h4>
<p> NAME: {{user.name}}</p>
AGE:  <input ng-model="user.age">
```

**Code**

```
  // assign value on page change.
  $scope.loadRecord = function(page) {
    $scope.user = $scope.users[page - 1] || {};
    $scope.user.age = $scope.user.age || 10;
  };

  $scope.loadRecord(1); //default load 1st page
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/rdXJkZYAKR94vZgjj3xW?p=preview)